# Configuring Global Error Pages on EAP 6.3 and later

Tags: jboss

We are trying to configure single custom error page for all our application deployed on JBOS EAP 6 server. As per the reference documents it is mentioned,there is no global web.xml on EAP 6 or 7. Is there still a way to configure custom error pages for all applications globally without having to define the error pages in each application's WEB-INF/web.xml individually?

Note: without editing application configuration.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

"The global web.xml is located at server/xxx/deployers/jbossweb.deployer, you can specify them there"

Please check this link:

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/81225